# UIPageViewController with images crash the app

Tags: objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have used an UIPageViewController
i want to display the 24 pages and each page is not a text its an image
in contentview controller i m using this code

```
 self.imgView.image=nil;
 self.imgView.image= [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"image%d.jpg",index+1]];

 if(self.categoryId==3 ||self.categoryId==4)
 {
     self.imgView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
 }
 else
 {
     self.imgView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
 }
```

but the problem is when i run the application and turn the pages
after 17 or 18 page it gives me an memory warning and my app get crashed

Comment: How do you respond to the memory warning? Do you actually free memory that is invisible. There is no need for keeping more than 3 pages in memory at a time. That is the page which is currently visible and those two next to it. So 16, 17 and 18 when 17 is currently visible. Everything else may be released (and created again when the user scrolls/pages to it).

Comment: i m just setting the image in image view. can you please explain how can i remove other pages? and how to free invisible memory? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and use:

```
NSString* imgFile = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"image%d",index+1];
NSString* pathToImageFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imgFile ofType:@"jpg"];
self.imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathToImageFile];
```

Indeed, `imageNamed` caches all the images you load through it. The cache gets bigger and bigger and it prevents memory from being freed appropriately.

Comment: Thanks. It's works but after completing navigation 3-4 times still app get crashed